# How do you fix a Resetting to invalid mark error for a BufferedInputStream?

Tags: java

I have read similar pages on why this happens, but not one of them has actually explained how you can fix this problem.

My program is converting a byte array to a .wav file and there are about 2 million values in the byte array.

```
String uploadedFileLocation = "C:\\";
AudioInputStream source;
AudioInputStream pcm;
InputStream b_in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
source = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(b_in));
pcm = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, source);
File newFile = new File(uploadedFileLocation + fileName);
AudioSystem.write(pcm, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, newFile);
source.close();
pcm.close();
```

Comment: What mark/reset? None here.

Comment: @downvoter, explain why it is bad.

Comment: It is bad because you haven't provided any evidence that `mark()` or `reset()` are being called, and because your edit makes nonsense of existing answers.

Comment: I reverted every change I made. I came here with a question, if I knew what `mark()` or `reset()` did, then I wouldn't have asked the question because I would know enough to find the answer without asking for help. Can you assume that I have been teaching myself java for under a year now, and I am very confused by every new thing in it, and your refusing to explain yourself doesn't help me at all. (it is my first language and probably my last because of people like you who just assume everyone has a java dictionary in their heads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a larger `readLimit` when calling `mark()`. If necessary you increase the buffer size passed to the `BufferedInputStream` constructor accordingly. The default value of this is undocumented but presently 8192.

HOWEVER In your situation the `BufferedInputStream` around the `ByteArrayInputStream` is completely pointless and should be removed. `ByteArrayInputStreams` are already marked and can support any amount of resetting.

Comment: Lets just say that I needed to have a `BufferedInputStream`. What would I do then?

Comment: @HarrietTubmanFan69 I've already answered that in the first paragraph. But you don't need it for the code you posted.

Comment: So because as far as I can tell, you can't increase `readLimit`, so you increase the buffer size? Or are those two things the same thing?

Comment: My original question is answered, but now it stops my program and gives the error message "EOFException: null"

Comment: You can't increase `readLimit` beyond the buffer size, so if you want > 8192 you have to increase both. Your final comment constitutes an entirely new question.

Comment: I understand that it is a new question, but I can't ask another question now, and I would like to have it answered as soon as possible.

Comment: That's not a reasonable expectation. You haven't provided a stack trace, for a start, or anything that constitutes a context. Clearly your byte array is incomplete, but how that happened is anybody's guess.